# Can one express $f'(x)$ with the same basis as one uses for $f$?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis

If I have an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ in space $L^2(a,b)$ and the generalized Fourier series expansion for $f$ would be:

$$f= \sum \langle f, \phi_n\rangle\phi_n,$$

then can one use the same basis $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ to give a generalized Fourier series expansion for $f'$? That is can one do:

$$f'= \sum \langle f', \phi_n\rangle\phi_n,$$

Is this true or false? Is it true in some cases, but generally not?

Thank you for any help! =)

Comment: It's certainly true if $f'$ is in $L^{2}$ (and you interpret your second displayed equation in the same sense as the first). Did you mean to ask if there is some formula relating $\langle f, \phi_{n}\rangle$ and $\langle f', \phi_{n}\rangle$?

Comment: Hi user @user86418 no I did not mean to ask that :) My question is related to the answer of my previous question in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802694/show-that-fx-is-orthogonal-to-fx-in-l2-pi-pi. There the user who answered my question wrote that for $f'$ the Fourier expansion is $f'=\sum \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n'$. I on the other hand expressed $f'$ like this: $f'=\sum \langle f', \phi_n\rangle \phi_n$ so I started to wonder, which way is generally correct and what not :) Did that clarify?

Comment: So is it correct to say that: If $f'$ belongs to the same space as $f$, then the above is true, in other case not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $f' = \sum \langle f', \phi_{n}\rangle \phi_{n}$ is just the ordinary $L^{2}$ expansion of $f'$, assuming $f'$ is in the same $L^{2}$ space as $f$ itself.

The formula $f' = \sum \langle f, \phi_{n}\rangle \phi_{n}'$ holds assuming $\{\phi_{n}\}$ is the "standard" exponential/trigonometric basis $\phi_{n}(x) = e^{inx}$ of $L^{2}\bigl([-\pi, \pi]\bigr)$:
$$
\langle f', \phi_{n}\rangle\phi_{n}
  = -\langle f, \phi_{n}'\rangle\phi_{n} 
  = in\langle f, \phi_{n}\rangle\phi_{n} 
  = \langle f, \phi_{n}\rangle\phi_{n}'.
$$
This chain of equality uses the fact that $\phi_{n}$ is an eigenfunction of the derivative.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)